# Can I manipulate associative array while reading in?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, datatable, datatables

I'm bringing in this array for datatables and putting it into an associative array. Before I was using datatables I was using straight PHP to create my table and could manipulate the indexed arrray, here's an example

```
    <?php
    foreach ($types as $val) {
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $val[0] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $val[1] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $val[5] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . number_format($val[2] * .01, 2) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $val[3] . '</td >';
    echo '<td>' . money_format('%2n', $val[4] * .01) . '</td>';



    switch ($val[5]) {
        case 'S';
            echo '<td>' . money_format('%2n', $val[3]) . '</td>';
            break;
        case 'U';
            echo '<td>U</td>';
            break;
        case 'H':
            $totalHourly = ($val[2] * .01) * ($val[4] * .01);
            echo '<td>' . $totalHourly . '</td>';
            break;
        case 'M':
            echo '<td>M</td>';
            break;
        default;
            if ($val[2] > 0) {
                $totalGross = ($val[2] * .01) * ($val[4] * .01);
                echo '<td>' . money_format('%.2n', $totalGross) . '</td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td>' . money_format('%.2n', $val[3]) . '</td>';
            }
    }

    echo '<td><a href=EmployeeInfo.php?empNum=' . $val[0] . '>Info</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href=EmployeePayroll.php?empNum=' . $val[0] . '>Payroll</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Now I am using datatables and from the example am using an associative array. The reason I'm using datatables is for the hide and show chid row. Here is an example of my associative array.

```
while ($row = db2_fetch_array($stmt)) {

        $load['data'][] = array(
            'empNum' => $row[0],
            'empName' => $row[1],
            'unitRate' => $row[2],
            'salary' => $row[3],
            'hourly' => $row[4],
            'appFlag' => $row[5],
            'app1' => $row[6],
            'app2' => $row[7],
            'app3' => $row[8],
            'app4' => $row[9],
            'app5' => $row[10],
            'uni1' => $row[11],
            'uni2' => $row[12],
            'uni3' => $row[13],
            'uni4' => $row[14],
            'uni5' => $row[15],
            'gross' => ($row[2] * .01) * ($row[4] * .01)
        );
    }
```

The very last line is the simplest way I have found of manipulating this array. Is there a way I can apply the same logic to my associative array the same way I did my indexed array? And if not, what is the best way of adding logic and then creating an associative array?

This is what I did.

```
while ($row = db2_fetch_array($stmt)) {
            $empNum = $row[0];
            $empName = $row[1];
            $unitRate = $row[2];
            $salary = $row[3];
            $hourly = $row[4];
            $appFlag = $row[5];
            $app1 = $row[6];
            $app2 = $row[7];
            $app3 = $row[8];
            $app4 = $row[9];
            $app5 = $row[10];
            $uni1 = $row[11];
            $uni2 = $row[12];
            $uni3 = $row[13];
            $uni4 = $row[14];
            $uni5 = $row[15];

       switch ($row[5]) {
            case 'S';
                $gross =  $row[3];
                break;
            default;
                if ($row[2] > 0) {
                    $gross = ($row[2] * .01) * ($row[4] * .01);
                } else {
                    $gross = $row[3];
                }
        }

         $load['data'][] = array(
             'empNum' => $empNum,
             'empName' => $empName,
             'unitRate' => $unitRate,
             'salary' => $salary,
             'hourly' => $hourly,
             'appFlag' => $appFlag,
             'app1' => $app1,
             'app2' => $app2,
             'app3' => $app3,
             'app4' => $app4,
             'app5' => $app5,
             'uni1' => $uni1,
             'uni2' => $uni2,
             'uni3' => $uni3,
             'uni4' => $uni4,
             'uni5' => $uni5,
             'gross' => $gross
         );
```

Comment: what you are doing is fine. Is it not working? Can also manipulate data in column rendering callback of datatables

Comment: The last line works fine, but I need to do more complicated logic. With switch and if statements.

Comment: So what is preventing you placing those switch and if statements in your while loop?

Comment: Well I tried to do that. I copy and pasted the switch statement from the first example and replaced the $row[] with the associative equivalent it didn't work, or I wasn't doing it correctly. As soon as I put an if or switch I get an error.

Comment: well you need to show the code that you tried and expand on what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to do it all in one shot. You can create your child array, manipulate it however you want, THEN stuff it into the parent array

```
$foo = array()
$foo['empnum'] = ...
...
$foo['gross'] = $foo['x'] * $foo['y'];
if ( ...) {
   $foo['if_results'] = ... :
}    
$data[] = $foo;
```

Note that you cannot embed if/switch inside the `... = array(...)` definition. if/switch are not function calls, they do not have return values, and therefore can be used in a context where they'd expected to be function calls.

Comment: THIS!!!!! Can I'm reading in the array indexed. Can I use the index instead of associative name and then assign it as an associative array? Example $foo = array() if ($row[1] == 'something) { $foo['result']  }

Comment: `$foo['result'] = $row['some_value_from_the_db']`, basically. or whatever else you want to stuff into the new array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct to go through your associative array and manipulate its content:

```
$data = array(
        'empNum' => $row[0],
        'empName' => $row[1],
        'unitRate' => $row[2],
        'salary' => $row[3],
        'hourly' => $row[4],
        'appFlag' => $row[5],
        'app1' => $row[6],
        'app2' => $row[7],
        'app3' => $row[8],
        'app4' => $row[9],
        'app5' => $row[10],
        'uni1' => $row[11],
        'uni2' => $row[12],
        'uni3' => $row[13],
        'uni4' => $row[14],
        'uni5' => $row[15],
        'gross' => ($row[2] * .01) * ($row[4] * .01)
    );
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = 1; // add your complicated logic here
}
$load['data'][] = $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well you are thinking you need to do the ifs and whiles directly in the array defenition. And that's not true. You can do it like this:

```
$count = 0;
while ($row = db2_fetch_array($stmt)) {
        $load['data'][] = array(
            'empNum' => $row[0],
            'empName' => $row[1],
            'unitRate' => $row[2],
            'salary' => $row[3],
            'hourly' => $row[4],
            'appFlag' => $row[5],
            'app1' => $row[6],
            'app2' => $row[7],
            'app3' => $row[8],
            'app4' => $row[9],
            'app5' => $row[10],
            'uni1' => $row[11],
            'uni2' => $row[12],
            'uni3' => $row[13],
            'uni4' => $row[14],
            'uni5' => $row[15],
            'gross' => ($row[2] * .01) * ($row[4] * .01)
        );
        if <condition> {
            $load['data'][$count]['uni3'] = <whatever>;
            $load['data'][$count]['gross'] = <whatever>;
        } else {
            $load['data'][$count]['uni5'] = <whatever>;
            $load['data'][$count]['gross'] = <whatever2>;
        }
        <any other code you what>
        $count++;
}
```

Comment: won't work. you'll be adding the whatevers to the parent array, not the new empnum/empname/etc... array. it'd have to be `$load['data'][index of new array]['uni3'] = ...`